# Exram.Gremlinq 12.3.0 How to implement Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, gremlinnet

Before I upgraded ExRam.Gremlinq.Core to 12.3.0 I had this piece of code (sample) working

```
g.V<User>()
  .As((__, user) => __.Emit()
      .Repeat(v => v.Out<FriendOf>())
      .As((___, friend) => ___.Select((node, friend))))
```

Now, my code doesn't compile as the new .As signature isn't recognizing Emit

[image]

How do I achieve this in new Gremlinq?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Loop` to enter a special loop-DSL. `Emit`, `Repeat` and `Until` are all available through the builder.